# Identifying inequalities for 3D region.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integral-inequality

I am having some difficulty identifying the bounds of a three-dimensional region.

I am asked to evaluate $\iiint_R (xz+3z)dV$, where $R$ is the region bounded by the cylinder $x^2 + z^2 = 9$ and the planes $x+y=3$, $z=0$, and $y=0$, above the $xy$-plane.

[image: Plotted by Grapher on MacOSX]

[image: A sketch of the region R]

So now that I've a sketch of the region $R$, I am trying to find the bounds of $x$, $y$, and $z$ but I'm always confused when it comes to identifying the correct bounds.

For example, I don't know which of the following for $x$ are correct:

$-3 \le x \le 3$

$-3 \le x \le 3-y$

(are both of them wrong?)

Could someone please give me some tips on how I should go about constructing the inequalities for this 3D region?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to decide what order you will integrate in.  As the integrand has no $y$ in it, that integral is easy to do and I would do it first.  In that case, you can take $x$ and $z$ to be fixed (they are supplied by the outer integrals) and you need to find the range in $y$.  $y$ can't be less than $0$ as that plane is one of you boundaries and can't be greater than $3-x$.  So the inner integral is $\int_0^{3-x}dy$.  Then if we do $x$ next, we have that $x$ ranges from $-\sqrt{9-z^2}$ to $\sqrt{9-z^2}$ and finally $z$ ranges from $0$ to $3$ because of the $xy$ plane restriction.  So our final integral becomes $$\int_{0}^3\int_{-\sqrt{9-z^2}}^{\sqrt{9-z^2}}\int_0^{3-x} (xz+3z)\;dy \;dx \; dz$$

Comment: I think $z$ need only range from $0$ to $3$ since the region is bounded below by the $xy$ plane.

Comment: Hmm - I really can't see how $x$ is as you have defined. From what I can see, shouldn't it be $-3 \le x \le 3$? The thing is, I'm not sure when to use which equation.

Comment: @NathanWilson: Say you are at $z=1$.  In that case, $x$ ranges from $-\sqrt 8$ to $+\sqrt 8$.  As we are inside the $z$ integral, we choose $z$ first, then figure out the range of $x$

Comment: @icurays1:  correct.  Fixed

Comment: Right. So if, assuming it's easier to start integrating with $z$ or $x$ first, will the boundaries still be the same?  (I don't think so).

Comment: I'm still confused as to how to identify the boundaries. Any possible resources you people could point me to? Thanks!

Comment: @NathanWilson:  The outer integral is the full range in whichever coordinate.  Here, if the outer one is $z$ it ranges from $0$, because we must be above the $xy$ plane, to $3$ because of the cylinder.  As you go in, each integral is at a particular value of the outer variables.  So if the next one in is $x$, we ask how much can $x$ vary, given the value of $z?$.  To stay within the cylinder, we get the range shown.  Finally, for $y$ we ask what is the range of $y$, given that $x,z$ are fixed?  At $x=3, y$ is required to be $0$.  At $x=0, y$ can range from $0$ to $3$